# Command line to extract all domain names referenced in a file

Tags: regex, powershell, text-extraction

I need a way to extract all domain names (I don't care about the full URL) in a file full of URLs.

Input:

```
<html xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" lang="en-US" style="font-size:calc(1em*0.625)" class="hiperf">
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.msn.com/" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://t-am.s-msn.com/sc/css/87/59a8b7d9f06b8bd9a73fa79c968252.css" media="all" />
<li id="sign-in-out"><a href="https://login.live.com/login.srf?wa=wsignin1.0&amp;rpsnv=12&amp;ct=1406822543&amp;rver=6.1.6195.0&amp;wp=MBI_SSL&amp;wreply=https://login.secure.blu.msn.com/wlsignin.aspx?ru=http%253a%252f%252ft.msn.com%252f&amp;lc=1033&amp;id=1184&amp;pcexp=True">Sign in</a></li>
```

Output:

```
ogp.me
www.facebook.com
www.msn.com
t-am.s-msn.com
login.live.com
login.secure.blu.msn.com
```

For example, this regex match works for what I need:

```
    https?:\/\/.*?\/
```

How do I accomplish this via command line?

I've tried...

```
    xidel --extract "https?://{.}/" http://t.msn.com >> testoutput.txt
```

...but my syntax is incorrect. If xidel is not the correct tool, I'm willing to use wget to download the page and then something else to parse it for all `http/s` references.

Comment: Can you post some of that "file full of URLs" and the expected output? And are you using GNU/Linux command-line or Windows?

Comment: Example input file: http://pastebin.com/qw47h4Yp

Expected output: http://pastebin.com/EguvdrqV
Windows command-line

Comment: sed in a pipe is probably an easier solution.

Comment: Wait, so your regex works fine but you only need to extract it?

Comment: The regex works to get the part of the URL I need: http://rubular.com/r/hepVqDny0E

I just can't get xidel to use/match that regex correctly

Comment: I agree with @ArtTaylor. `sed` or anything GNU/Linux is going to be better. Good luck with your windows command-line!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use your regex, you can do:

```
gc input.html | %{[regex]::matches($_, "https?:\/\/(.*?)\/")} | %{(new-object system.uri $_.value).host}
```

to get a list of host names.

If this isn't flexible enough, you could use [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to parse the HTML and extract the hrefs.

If you want to remove duplicates, you can use `select -uniq`:

```
gc input.html | %{[regex]::matches($_, "https?:\/\/(.*?)\/")} | %{(new-object system.uri $_.value).host} | select -uniq
```

Comment: this is really great! I realize I can write the output to a file with >> outfile.txt but how could I make it to include no duplicates? just one instance of each string found?

Comment: Where do you get the gc command/program?  Is it for Windows? Oh - is it  Powershell?

Comment: @NealWalters - `gc` is a powershell alias for `Get-Content` so you could also use `Get-Content input.html | ...`

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use regex unless you absolutely have to.  Since this is HTML you can use the IE COM object.

```
$ie = new-object -com "InternetExplorer.Application"
Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
$ie.Navigate("D:\SavedPage.htm")
```

Once you do this, you can then reference the links via $ie.Links.

Comment: this is neat and all, but I definitely don't want IE to actually have to load the page on the server, I'd much prefer to grab a plain-text version of the page and search across it.  This is safer for security reasons.

I also don't want just links, I need every img src, script, form action, css, and href that starts with https or http

Comment: If you need more than just the link and don't really care about where the strings come from then you're right.  I wouldn't want to use the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Your immediate problem is how you are trying to use a regular expression with xidel.  xidel expects an XPath for its `--extract` argument.  You would need to set up a path that includes "`matches(...)`".  This would be brittle with poorly-formed HTML.

Alternatively, for a quick meatball surgery to extract the hostname, the following will work if you have lynx<sup>1</sup>, GNU sed<sup>2</sup>, and sort<sup>3</sup> installed.

`lynx http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=qw47h4Yp -force_html -nonumbers -image_links -dump -source |grep http |gsed --regexp-extended "s/^.*[^\/][^\/]\/\/([^\/]+).*/\1/" |sort -u`

Running this on OS X, I get the following output, which can be redirected to a file.

```
advertising.microsoft.com
b.scorecardresearch.com
col.stb00.s-msn.com
g.msn.com
go.microsoft.com
login.secure.blu.msn.com
msnportalusentmx.112.2O7.net
news.msn.com
onlinehelp.microsoft.com
support.microsoft.com
t-am.s-msn.com
t.autos.msn.com
t.entertainment.msn.com
t.healthyliving.msn.com
t.living.msn.com
t.money.msn.com
t.msn.com
t.sports.msn.com
t.weather.msn.com
twitter.com
wst.s-msn.com
www.bing.com
www.facebook.com
www.foxsports.com
www.microsoft.com
www.msn.com
www.outlook.com
www.skype.com
```

<sup>1</sup> http://lynx.isc.org/lynx2.8.8/index.html contains Windows binaries if you don't use cygwin or an equivalent.

<sup>2</sup> See https://superuser.com/questions/390241/sed-for-windows for some help on acquiring GNU sed for Windows and dealing with platform-specific quoting issues.

<sup>3</sup> I would recommend GNU Coreutils (http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/) for this.  Windows binaries are available at http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm.

Comment: thanks for this great information, I've learned allot.  I went with another solution simply cause PowerShell is already native to Windows, but this is valuable for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

I think Xidel can be used for this:

```
xidel -q input.html -e '//substring-before(substring-after(@href,"//"),"/")' | sort -u
```

...maybe an xquery function exists to even shorter it. Like the following, which does *not* work!

```
xidel -q input.html -e '//domain-name(@href)' | sort -u
```

Only hrefs may not cut it, so here's a more complete selector, and I see you're using Windows, so I reversed the quotation. Also use the Win32 version of UX's sort!

```
xidel -q "http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=qw47h4Yp" -e "(//@*)/substring-before(substring-after(.,'//'),'/')" | sort.exe -u
```

Although the output from the above line is extensive... this doesn't cut it either, because it misses domains like "ogp.me". So you should probably use xidel with the extract() function (=regex)  and $raw variable, so it won't parse the URL/file as being XML/HTML, but as plain text. I haven't toyed with a xidel line for you that does this yet.